# Selenium C# Tests on Various Browsers

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, qa-developer, selenium-webdriver-c#

I would like to run my tests on multiple browsers but NOT in parallel. I want to provide a pop up to the user to choose which browser (IE, Chrome, Firefox) to execute all tests on when first started.

If I run the BrowserChoice as its own class in a different project, the code works. If I try to initialize it before a test in the same project with the selenium tests, it never executes and fails.

**CODE**:

```
public static void BrowserChoice()
{            
   int userInput;
   Console.Write("Which browser would you like to run tests with?\n");
   Console.Write("Press A for FireFox\n");
   Console.Write("Press B for ChromeDriver\n");
   Console.Write("Press C for Internet Explorer\n\n\n");
   userInput = Console.Read();

   if (userInput == 'A')
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Firefox will execute the tests!\n");
      IWebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
   }
   else if (userInput == 'B')
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Chrome will execute the tests!\n");
      IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
   }
   else if (userInput == 'C')
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Internet Explorer will execute the tests!\n");
      IWebDriver webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
   }
   else
   {
      Console.Write("User did not enter a valid input!");
      Console.ReadLine();
      Console.ReadLine();
   }
}
```

**Test Initialize Code:**

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Setup()
{
   XmlConfigurator.Configure();
   Browser.BrowserChoice(driver);
   driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Url"));
   driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
}
```

Comment: Do you have two separate projects?  It looks to me like you do.  A class library and a console application?

Comment: Is it just that the IWebDriver object being instantiated is only within the scope of the if statement? Given it's a static method do you just need a static IWebDriver variable that gets returned to the caller?
In my project I just added a Settings.Settings file that contains an option for which browser so I select it there before running the tests in each browser.